# Screwy code logic for social network

Tags: php, codeigniter

Node1id is the user that sent the request and node2id is the user that is receiving the request. How would I limit the code below to only display the request to node2id. I tried doing:

```
$row->relationType == 'requested' && node2id == $userid
```

but it doesn't seem to want to work. Any ideas?

[image]

```
<?php
$selectedId = $_REQUEST['id'];
$myuserid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
$query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE node1id = '{$myuserid}' AND node2id = '${selectedId}'");
      foreach($query1->result() as $row) {
      if ($row->relationType == 'requested') { ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function() {
                    $("#addFriend").replaceWith('<span id="requestAlert"><span class="font1">wants to be your friend&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="acceptRequest" value="Accept" style="width: 60px; height: 28px" class="button1" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="denyRequest" value="Deny" style="width: 50px; height: 28px" class="button1" /></span>');
                });
            </script>
<?php } } ?>
```

Comment: What exactly is `$userid`? The ID of the logged in user, I presume? Did you try a `var_dump()` to see what the values actually are when you compare them?

Comment: Yes $userid is the logged in user. and actually in the code i have implemented it is $myuserid. And okay I'll try it. I'm just wondering if this is the correct logic to use.

Comment: And actually node2id should be: $row->node2id.

Comment: I think you should just make the relationType part of the WHERE clause . . .

Comment: Yeah it doesn't seem like it is going to work. What it's doing is displaying to node1id. and when I add node2id = '{$myuserid}' to the SQL code or add it to the if statement it won't process correctly

Comment: http://pastebin.com/FPW208mv - here is my full php code.

Comment: SELECT * FROM friends WHERE relationType = 'requested' AND node2id = '${myuserid}'

Comment: Well see with that it is now displaying the js for all the users. it needs to just be pointed where node1id and node2id equal to the users in question. then it needs to show the request to node2id. thats the problem

Comment: Oh, I see . . . Does that mean you have node2id and node1id switched in your WHERE clause?

Comment: What do you mean by switched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Based on your comment.  Here's what I think it should look like from your description:

```
<?php
  $selectedId = $_REQUEST['id'];
  $myuserid = $this->session->userdata('userid');
  $query1 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM friends WHERE relationType = 'requested' AND node2id = '${myuserid}' AND node1id ='$selectedId'");
  foreach($query1->result() as $row) { ?>
       <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).ready(function() {
             $("#addFriend").replaceWith('<span id="requestAlert"><span class="font1">wants to be your friend&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="acceptRequest" value="Accept" style="width: 60px; height: 28px" class="button1" />&nbsp;<input type="submit" id="denyRequest" value="Deny" style="width: 50px; height: 28px" class="button1" /></span>');
          });
       </script>
  <?php }  ?>
```

Comment: No sir. When mike visits joes page, and joe has sent mike a request, the request will be displayed on joes page.

Comment: Okay, updated answer - should now only show if there is a request from that user to the current user

Comment: And that fixed it. thanks man. This stuff can be confusing at times lol.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/pF9VZQy2 - here is my next problem when i click accept and pass the data through jquery ajax, the update statement in that controller won't work. Do you know anything about that?